# javascript function stopi does not work

Tags: javascript

this is JS code
here function stopi does not work. what problem ?
/* 
Ideally, you'd add as much clarification and context as you could outside the code block, since you're no longer constrained to mixing code and meta-information about the code.

From a cursory examination of your screenshot, the comments appear to be inserted by a TA or instructor as part of a course you're completing, and are probably not particularly relevant to your question. Remove them, and summarise the necessary details outside the code block.
*/

```
function fun(){ 

    var stopping = setInterval(_fun,1500); // interval
}

function _fun(){ 

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
    //var doc = document.getElementById(""+i+"");
    document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = i ;

    switch(i)
  {
        case 1:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("1").bgColor == "orange")
        {
            document.getElementById("1").bgColor = "red";

            break;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("1").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("1").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("1").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("2").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("2").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("2").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("3").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("3").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("3").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("4").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("4").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("4").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("5").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("5").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("5").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("6").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("6").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("6").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("7").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("7").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("7").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("8").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("8").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("8").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
    case 9:
    {
        if(document.getElementById("9").bgColor == "yellow"){
            document.getElementById("9").bgColor = "orange";
            break;
        }
        else
        document.getElementById("9").bgColor = "yellow";
    break;
    }
  }
}
function stopi(){
    clearInterval(stopping);
}
```

this is html code

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="New.js">
</script>
<p id="pp"></p>
<button onclick="fun()"> Start </button>
<button onclick="stopi()"> Cancel </button>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1" style="width:15%">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>       
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>       
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>       
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var stopping = setInterval(_fun,1500);` is local to the `fun` method... declare the variable as global - just remove `var` from the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function fun(){ 

    var stopping = setInterval(_fun,1500); // interval
}
```

stopping is local variable for `fun()` function. declare it as global so you can access to it from other functions

```
    var stopping;

    function fun(){  
        stopping = setInterval(_fun,1500); // interval
    }
    function stopi(){
        clearInterval(stopping);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare `stopping` variable outside function:

```
var stopping;

function fun(){ 
    stopping = setInterval(_fun,1500); // interval
}
```